# iOS Crash when repeatedly calling Vision with CVPixelBuffer

Tags: swift, machine-learning, computer-vision, core-video, apple-vision

I have an application that repeatedly tells a `VNImageRequestHandler` object to perform a `VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest` from a `CVPixelBuffer` which is delivered to me from the iOS Camera.

I frequently see crashes from Fabric that look like this:

`#0 Crashed: com.apple.main-thread`

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000`

`0  CoreVideo`

`CVPixelBufferGetWidth + 20`

I already try and validate my `CVPixelBuffer` using an extension before I pass it to vision like this:

```
var isValid: Bool {
    let cvBufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(self)
    let cvBufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(self)
    let size = CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(self)
    let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(self)

    guard cvBufferWidth > 0 && cvBufferHeight > 0 && size > 0 && bytesPerRow > 0 else {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

I also only ever process one `CVPixelBuffer` at a time (Apple has a sample project that said this is best practice in the comments).

What should I do? I can't seem to shake this bug!! Should I lock the `CVPixelBuffer`'s base address?

`CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(self, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly)`

Apple says don't do this if using the GPU and I know vision will use the GPU in some cases.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this issue?

Comment: Yeah, I stopped using vision and am using another commercial face recognition vendor.